# Stability of a system

Tags: discrete-signals, homework, stability

- Is the system $y[n] = x[n] - x[n-1]$ stable or unstable ?
- If unstable, can you please give some examples of input signals for which the system becomes unstable?

Comment: Homework? Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Differentiation and Integration in continuous time are unstable. Summation in discrete time also unstable so I am guessing the difference equation also an unstable one.

Comment: Is there any input function for which the above signal is unstable. I took sine, step signals are inputs, that seem to be stable system..!!

Comment: metal, your first comment is factually incorrect.  (or half incorrect.)  oh, i guess a continuous-time differentiator is BIBO stable only if the bounded input is also continuous.  but does that continuity mean anything for discrete-time bounded signals?

Comment: Continuous time differentiator is BIBO unstable for an unit step signal, which gives delta function as output whose value at t=0 is theoretically infinite. And yes the input signal is discontinuous at t =0, but overall the system is considered an unstable one..

Comment: did you read what i said, metal?  did you think about the question that i asked?

Comment: I've missed it Robert. Yeah any type of bounded signal is allowed in my question. Thank you..

Comment: well, the point was that the **discontinuity** of the input is solely to blame for the unbounded output of a continuous-time differentiator.  so it is not BIBO stable.  but *discontinuity* doesn't have meaning in discrete-time signals.  so the discrete-time differentiator cannot be BIBO unstable for the same reason as the continuous-time differentiator is.  and, as it turns out, the discrete time differentiator is trivially shown to be BIBO because the difference of two finite numbers is also finite.

Comment: @robert.... Awesum explanation. Thank you so much for your time to explain this to me.

Comment: Just for the record, any FIR filter must be stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For BIBO stability in the case of discrete time, there is a necessary and sufficient condition given by $\sum |h[n]| < \infty$ that is if the impulse response is absolute summable then the system is BIBO stable. Clearly
$$h[n] = \delta[n] - \delta[n-1]$$ and it has a finite support, the impulse response is absolutely summable and therefore BIBO stable.

Comment: I don't think ["support"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) is the correct term to use in this argument.  the impulse response for a simple first-order LPF: $$ h[n] = a^n \ u[n] $$ where $|a|<1$ and $u[n]$ is the discrete unit step function, that $h[n]$ does not have finite support yet it is BIBO stable.

Comment: oh, i see, Arka, you're not saying that "finite support" is necessary, just that it is sufficient.  okay, i agree.

Answer (score 1):

Stability has different meanings depending on the system you are observing. Here, you have a discrete system, which is linear, and time-invariant. The most common stability criterion in this case is the so-called bounded-input, bounded-output (BIBO) stability.

The question of stability is thus: **if an input is bounded in amplitude, is the output always bounded too?**

In other words, if $|x[n]| \le B$, do we always have some (other) bound $B'$ such that $|y[n]| \le B'$?

Here, basic  inequalities give the response: $$|y[n]| = |x[n]-x[n-1]| \le  |x[n]| +|x[n-1]| \le 2B$$

As said by  @robertbristow-johnson, this can be generalized to FIR (finite impulse response) filters, since you will have:

$$|y[n]| \le B\sum|h[n]|  $$
with a finite sum of terms, always bounded, for instance by the number $L$ of non-zero terms (always finite for a FIR system), times the maximum amplitude coefficient $h_{M} = \max |h[n]|$:

$$|y[n]| \le BL h_{M}   $$

But remember that there exist infinite-support  systems which are BIBO too.